# How do I determine the cause of Qt's "*** is not a valid Qt plugin" error?

Tags: qt, plugins, dll, qt4, pyside

When I print the value of errorString from my QPluginLoader object, I get this:

> The file 'C:/pyprojects/test/qsqlpsqld4.dll' is not a valid Qt plugin.

I would like to avoid some days worth of doing the time consuming "guess-and-check" methodology that my current internet searches reveal (so far none of them seem relevant anyways).

Is there a way for me to get the Qt library itself to tell me why it is refusing to load this plugin?

I don't want to guess; I want to *know*.

Context:

I am on Windows 7 running Qt 4.8.5 (32-bit, MinGW) and the qsqlpsqld4.dll file is also 32-bit and compiled with MinGW.

I am using PySide to interact with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like PySide wants the non-debug version of the library.

When you are in debug mode, it references libraries that end in `d.dll` or `d4.dll`.  Try grabbing the plugin that does not have the `d` in the end of the dll name, and put it in the same spot.

I recently went through the throws of compiling one of the mysql qt plugins for 4.8.4 for visual studio 2010 and came out the victor.

Let me know if making that change fixes it or not.  :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is at least easy to check, so I tried it.  No dice :(

I thank you for trying to help, though keep in mind that I am hoping someone can find a way to make this error message become more specific.  Perhaps there is some config option that can be set in the API or environment that creates more verbose output that includes internal errors.  That would be ideal, and it would let others in the future know exactly how to troubleshoot this regardless of the actual cause.

Answer (score 0):

PySide does not support MinGW. Official PySide distributions are compiled with Visual C++. You need to recompile your plugin with compatible Visual C++ version. By default PySide for Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2 is compiled with VC++ 2008. PySide for Python 3.3 is compiled with VC++ 2010 compiler.

Comment: I am using MinGW because I gave up in frustration after a couple days of messing with the Microsoft SDK. It doesn't bother to set up its own environment variables correctly when it installs, and I suspect that there were other things wrong too.  Stuff like [this](http://bit.ly/19hv3Zg). The only way I will subject myself to that kind of pain again is if I can get Qt to _tell me explicitly_ that this is the problem.  Otherwise, I'm afraid I can't justify the days of effort on a "gee, maybe" guess.  Thank you for trying though; you may very well be right.

Comment: I'm also hoping to create an answer here that will help _everyone_ faced with this vague error message, not just the few people that happen to have the same root-cause as me.  There is currently no way for people to even know if my solution (should I find it) is relevant to them or not.

Comment: @chadjoan I will try to build the Postgres driver with Microsoft SDK, please be patient